# Invoking uninstall program option from control panel using NSIS script

Tags: windows, scripting, nsis

I am building an installer wrapper for a program but I don't know where the uninstall.exe is or how it is executed.

My problem is my wrapper installer creates desktop shortcuts which donot get deleted when I uninstall the program from Control panel.

I also tried looking at the registry but I could not find the path to the uninstaller anywhere.

I want to know is there any way using NSIS by which I can uninstall the program by invoking Control Panel's uninstall option or finding the uninstall for the program and using ExecWait to run uninstall.exe and then simply delete the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The application to be uninstalled registers with Windows under the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`. You simply need to read the `UninstallString` value from the app's subkey and invoke the command line it specifies.

Comment: Unlikely in this case but it can also be under HKCU for single-user installers...